# eBay Trading API run-time error when sending request

Tags: vb6, ebay-api

I am having problems sending a `GeteBayDetails` request.
I use this code (VB6, yes I know) for `FindPopularItems`, `GeteBayTime`, etc,
and it works fine.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim httpCnct As XMLHTTP40
Dim xmlDoc As FreeThreadedDOMDocument40
Dim ebayurl As String
Dim devid As String
Dim appid As String
Dim certid As String
Dim xmlstring As String
Dim ebaytoken As String
Dim title As String
Dim itemid As String
Dim price As String

ebayurl = "http://open.api.sandbox.ebay.com/shopping?"

Set httpCnct = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0")

httpCnct.open "POST", ebayurl, False

httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-APP-ID", appid
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-VERSION", "857"
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID", "3"
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "FindPopularItems"
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING", "XML"

xmlstring = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
  "<FindPopularItemsRequest xmlns=""urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"">" & _
  "<QueryKeywords>Camera</QueryKeywords>" & _
  "</FindPopularItemsRequest>"

httpCnct.send xmlstring  'xmlDoc   Sending the raw string works.
```

---

But when I modify the code slightly, using the url, the headers and the xml from the API test tool,
like this:

```
ebayurl = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"

Set httpCnct = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0")

httpCnct.open "POST", ebayurl, False

httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-APP-ID", appid
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", certid
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-VERSION", "903"
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID", "0"
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GeteBayDetails"
httpCnct.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING", "XML"

xmlstring = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
 "<GeteBayDetailsRequest xmlns=""urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"">" & _
 "<RequesterCredentials> <eBayAuthToken>" & ebaytoken &     "</eBayAuthToken>" & _
 "</RequesterCredentials> </GeteBayDetailsRequest>"

httpCnct.send xmlstring  'xmlDoc   Sending the raw string works.
```

I get

> Run-time error '-2146697208 (800c0008)': The download of the specified
>   resource has failed

`ebaytoken` is set to my token. `devid`, `appid`, `certid` are set earlier in the program and are the same in both instances. The XML is okay, the headers and the URL are those from the API test tool.

Anyone got any idea what's going on here?
Thanks

Comment: Use Fiddler or other http trafic monitoring tool to find out what request is sent and what is received from the server -- don't guess it.

Comment: Thank you. I am still none the wiser. The request that works shows in Fiddler with the full Host and URL, and all the request headers set by the program  are displayed. The request that doesn't work shows as 'Tunnel to api.sandbox.ebay.com:443' and none of the program-set headers are displayed. It shows Body 0, presumably meaning nothing got through.

Comment: I have typed in 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll' to the browser address bar and I get a response (an xml message, displayed in the browser) so the url is right and the site responds, but it seems the program is not sending the message properly.

Comment: Try using `CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")` without any version. I do get a `GeteBayDetailsResponse` for failure with copy/paste of your code. It must be a filtering issue with your internet access.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it makes no difference. Given this problem and that the so-called eBay developers program has now got rid of the API Test Tool, about the only useful thing on there, and it's almost impossible to post to their forums to ask for help, I am going to say No to this project.